# debug assertion failed using sprintf in c++

Tags: c++, debugging, printf, assertion

I keep getting the "debug assertion failed" error when i debug my code

It seems to fail at the sprintf line in the function below:

```
void GetReference(int side)
{   
    for (int j=0; j<exposeNumber; j++)
    {
        image = cvQueryFrame(capture); // get the first frame of video

        sprintf(fileName, "RefImage%i", (side*exposeNumber + j));

        cvSaveImage(fileName, image);

        wait(200);

    }
}
```

"exposeNumber" is equal to 5 and "side" can either be 0 or 1

Cheers
Chris

Comment: it also gives the warning below when i build it

c:\users\bloomy\documents\my dropbox\integrated scanner\integrated scanner\integrated scanner.cpp(283): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

Comment: const char fileName = 0;

Comment: Are you sure? The first argument of `sprintf()` is a `char*`, and with that you'll be passing in a `const char`, resulting in a compiler error, not a runtime debug assertion.

Comment: yeah its definitely a debug assertion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fileName` MUST be big enough. And a `char*`. And **not** `NULL`. For example:

```
char fileName[1024];
```

or

```
char* fileName = new char[ 1024 ];
//..
delete[] fileName;
```

Or something smaller here. As I see, I guess 32 or 64 would be big enough.

I'm pretty sure the assertion fails because of `NULL` (or `0`, which is the same here) pointer (`fileName`)

Comment: Brilliant! Your second solution seemed to work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm glad that I helped :) :) Good luck with the program ;) And accept, please, as this solves your issue :)